# How should I implement user authentication/roles for an Electron desktop app?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, electron, openid-connect, desktop-application

I'm designing the architecture for a college project and I don't know how to deal with the user authentication and authorization part of it. The project is a desktop Electron app which would need two types (hence the *roles*) of users. They both need to be authenticated in order to use the app, and depending on their identity, they will have different authorizations. Since the project is meant to be used by teachers and students as part of a laboratory class after it is done, I don't think more than 30 people will be using it at the same time.

My first thought was using a PostrgeSQL database in AWS for this and implementing the authentication myself, but this means that users will have to sign up and create a new profile, **which means remembering yet another *<username/email, password>***. Trying to avoid this, I read a bit about **OAuth 2.0 and OIDC**, and how it can be used to authenticate and authorize users without implementing either of those tasks oneself, but rather delegating the task to OIDC. I created a free account with [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and thought about using it for the OIDC integration but after reading about 40 pages of an "OIDC integration handbook" they offer for free, I could not know if I would be able to distinguish my user base through these roles or tags as I mentioned. I just followed the steps in the tutorial handbook and tried to understand how the auth flow worked, but that didn't give me any information on my question.

So all in all what I want to know is: **is it possible to implement this with Auth0 (free account) without having to use a third-party database solution (such as PostgreSQL with AWS)? If not, what would you recommend me to look into? Preferrably a solution that will let me discriminate between the two types of users BUT at the same time taking advantage of the OIDC implementation of Google for example**.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate solutions here:

**DESKTOP AUTHENTICATION**

The 2 standard requirements are:

- Use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- Login via System Browser

You listen for a login response via one of these mechanisms (I prefer the latter):

- Loopback web server
- Private URI scheme OS notification

My blog has some [tutorials + code samples](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/) that use Electron. You can run both of the above listening options and see what you prefer.

**API AUTHORIZATION WITH ROLES**

You need to make roles available to the API via claims. This can be done by either of these mechanisms (I prefer the latter):

- Including roles in access tokens via Auth0
- Get the API to read user roles from its own database

My [Authorization blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) discusses building up a claims object in an easy to extend way. The main objective is usually for API OAuth processing to result in an object something like this:

```
class UserPrincipal {

  // The technical user id from the access token 
  string sub;

  // The user id from your own database
  string userId;

  // The user's roles
  string[] roles;

}
```

Given that object you can do things like this:

- Use role based authorization when needed
- Serve up user resources after login from your application data

**TO SUMMARISE**

Auth0 will meet some of your requirements and may be all you need in the early days. You will probably need to manage non OAuth user data in your API at some point though.

Happy to answer any follow up questions ..

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to check out the links you provided and will mark it as resolved if they solve my problem :)